# Strange behavior of a macro that uses another macro

Tags: c++, preprocessor

I've got a question about macros in C++;

My code:

```
#define a [i]
#define b(i) t a

int main(){
 int t[10];
 int i=0;
 b(i+1)=1;
}
```

Wanted result after preprocessor does its job:

```
int main(){
 int t[10];
 int i=0;
 t[i+1]=1;
}
```

Actual result:

```
int main(){
 int t[10];
 int i=0;
 t[i]=1;
}
```

I understand what is happening, but is there any way I can force preprocessor to do what i want? (so first replace code in macro b, than interpret this code as part of macro?)

Comment: Simple solution - do not use preprocessor

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: Pass I into a() as well?

Comment: No, there isn't. Why can't you define a with an argument?

Comment: The `b` macro doesn't use its argument `i` at all. The `i+1` isn't being passed to the `a` macro, so it's not going to show up in the preprocessed code.

Comment: I don't see why this is downvoted. The question is well formulated, providing everything it needs. Not liking the question's subject matter is not a good reason for downvoting.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It's at least unclear, what the OP expects? The preprocessor just works as expected, there's nothing _"strange"_ or weird in this case. That's why I down and close voted.

Comment: What OP is going to use it for is unclear (and may be a bad idea). The question itself is in the upper percentile of question quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This set of macros produces the desired result.

```
#define a(i) [i]
#define b(i) t a(i)
```

Example test.cpp

```
#define a(i) [i]
#define b(i) t a(i)

int main(){
 int t[10];
 int i=0;
 b(i+1)=1;
}
```

Then using `g++ -E test.cpp` the output is:

```
# 1 "test.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "test.cpp"



int main(){
 int t[10];
 int i=0;
 t [i+1]=1;
}
```